# How to register mac for distributing my iphone applications

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have developed a music application .i have run it in ipod .It is working properly .but now i want to distribute my application.For that i need to register my mac pc but my mac pc is not registered.So,please anybody help me or give any hints in  how to register my mac pc for distributing my iphone app

when i am running my application for distribution it gives me an error :

```
cd /Users/uttambeldar/Desktop/DietySongs
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.5
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.2.sdk -L/Users/uttambeldar/Desktop/DietySongs/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/uttambeldar/Desktop/DietySongs/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/uttambeldar/Desktop/DietySongs/build/DietySongs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DietySongs.build/Objects-normal/i386/DietySongs.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework MessageUI -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework MediaPlayer -o /Users/uttambeldar/Desktop/DietySongs/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DietySongs.app/DietySongs
ld: duplicate symbol _main in /Users/uttambeldar/Desktop/DietySongs/build/DietySongs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DietySongs.build/Objects-normal/i386/main-13B8478E.o and /Users/uttambeldar/Desktop/DietySongs/build/DietySongs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DietySongs.build/Objects-normal/i386/main-26D6EFA4.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ld: duplicate symbol _main in /Users/uttambeldar/Desktop/DietySongs/build/DietySongs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DietySongs.build/Objects-normal/i386/main-13B8478E.o and /Users/uttambeldar/Desktop/DietySongs/build/DietySongs.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DietySongs.build/Objects-normal/i386/main-26D6EFA4.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You don't need to register your Mac. Not sure where you got that from. You only need to register any devices you use for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To distribte your application, you need also a Developer Licence from Apple which costs 99$/Year. If you already bought it, you have to set up your mac. I use [this](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/04/24/tutorial-list-guideline-for-building-ad-hoc-application-for-iphone/) manual. It's just great.

Answer (score 0):

From your error message it seems that your target's Base SDK is not set to an iPhone OS SDK.